# How can I position this text in this <span> so it display in a line

Tags: html, reactjs, positioning

I have this `<span>` that creates this below image output:

```
        <li>
            <a onClick={onSearchPageClick} role="presentation">
                <span className="icon is-medium">
                    <i className="fas fa-search" />
                </span>{' '}
                Search
            </a>
        </li>
```

Image output:

[image]

Then I have this code using `span` but text is under the icon:

```
<li>
    <a onClick={onProfilePageClick} role="presentation">
        <span className="icon is-medium">
            <i className="fas fa-user" />
        </span>{' '}
        <div>
            {authUser && Array.isArray(authUser.roles) && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.USER) ? (
                <div>Dashboard</div>
            ) : (
                <div>Sign in</div>
            )}
    </div>
        </a>
</li>
```

[image]

Please advice how to do this I have tried for hours

Comment: Try removing the `<div>`s after the `<span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sky-zh5tg?file=/src/App.js:0-531

In order to create a working example I have removed some of the logic that was posted in the original code

the code just utilizes flex box:

```
   <li style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
      <a onClick={() => console.log("clicked")} style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <span className="icon is-medium">
          <div style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>avatar</div>
        </span>
        <div>{authUser ? <div>Dashboard</div> : <div>Sign in</div>}</div>
      </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<span>` tag is rendered inline, whereas the `<div>` tag is not. You can either use `<span>` or you can style your `<div>`, like:

```
<div style={{display: 'inline'}}>
   // your code goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change anything in your code. Just add these  CSS flexbox properties on anchor tag.

```
li a{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

In fact this will align your `icon` and `sign in` text exactly to the center both horizontally and vertically.